# How to get the Markdown Viewer addon of Firefox to work on Linux?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, markdown

I've installed the [Markdown Viewer](https://github.com/Thiht/markdown-viewer) Firefox addon, but I cannot get it to work on my Ubuntu installation. Firefox is my browser of choice and I am trying to move to Markdown in Vim as my basic text-writing software. Is there a way I can get this to work?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had to manually edit my `~/.mozilla/firefox/<PROFILE>/mimeTypes.rdf`. [This review](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/markdown-viewer/reviews/423328/) of the addon says:

> For linux users, try to add "md" to .mozilla/*.default/mimeTypes.rdf this line : mdin text/plain section :)

Hmm. I couldn't find a `text/plain` section, but I found [this page](http://www.ryanchapin.com/Home?article_id=737) is helpful:

> If there is not yet an existing RDF node for 'text/plain' add it, and add "md" as a file extension.
>
> ```
> <RDF:Description RDF:about="urn:mimetype:text/plain"
>        NC:value="text/plain"
>        NC:fileExtensions="md"
>        NC:description="Text Document">
>    <NC:handlerProp RDF:resource="urn:mimetype:handler:text/plain"/>
> </RDF:Description>
> ```

However, what I ended up doing was:

```
<RDF:Description RDF:about="urn:mimetype:text/plain; charset=utf8"
               NC:value="text/plain; charset=utf8"
               NC:handleInternal="true"
               NC:description="Markdown Document">
  <NC:fileExtensions>md</NC:fileExtensions>
  <NC:fileExtensions>mkd</NC:fileExtensions>
  <NC:fileExtensions>mdown</NC:fileExtensions>
  <NC:fileExtensions>markdown</NC:fileExtensions>
  <NC:handlerProp RDF:resource="urn:mimetype:handler:text/plain; charset=utf8"/>
</RDF:Description>
```

It seemed to be the `NC:handInternal="true"` that did the trick. Interestingly, it seems it does not work with the `text/markdown` or `text/x-markdown` MIME types. The `charset=utf8` is because I write all my Makefiles in Unicode.

Comment: One have to restart Firefox after modifying the `mimeTypes.rdf` file for changes to be applied.

Comment: I just installed the Firefox Markdown Viewer on Kubuntu 12.04 and it worked perfectly out of the box. No tweaks required.

Comment: Did not work for me in Ubuntu 16.04 with FF 54.0. @Brad's solution did work.

Comment: @KeithRobertson Yeah, this solution is dated. You see it's from 3-1/2 years ago...

Answer (score 61):

Happy to report that I was able to find a solution that I provided here:

https://github.com/Thiht/markdown-viewer/issues/62#issuecomment-277702230

I've also copied it here for reference:

On Linux, you'll need to create a new MIME type here:

`~/.local/share/mime/packages/text-markdown.xml`

With the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<mime-info xmlns='http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/shared-mime-info'>
  <mime-type type="text/plain">
    <glob pattern="*.md"/>
    <glob pattern="*.mkd"/>
    <glob pattern="*.markdown"/>
  </mime-type>
</mime-info>
```

Then run:

`update-mime-database ~/.local/share/mime`

Comment: Could you copy it here? http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/350309

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me in Ubuntu 16.04, Firefox 57.0.3, but **only** with the Markdown Viewer **Webext** add-on. With the Markdown Viewer add-on, it just displayed source/plain text.

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 17.10 with FF 59.0.1 and the [GitLab Markdown Viewer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/gitlab-markdown-viewer/) add-on.

Comment: It really helped. For those who get an error that the file is not available for editing, please ensure you create the directories first with "mkdir -p ~/.local/share/mime/packages" and then you create the file. It really works well.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to solve the same problem by putting the following line into `~/.mime.types`.

```
text/plain                                   md markdown
```

Answer (score 2):

Building on the solution provided by @Brad I fixed the problem for *all* users on an Ubuntu 16.04 machine, not just the current one:

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/share/mime/packages
sudo gedit /usr/local/share/mime/packages/text-markdown.xml
sudo update-mime-database /usr/local/share/mime
```

The file I created is the same as in the solution provided by @Brad -

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<mime-info xmlns='http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/shared-mime-info'>
  <mime-type type="text/plain">
    <glob pattern="*.md"/>
    <glob pattern="*.mkd"/>
    <glob pattern="*.markdown"/>
  </mime-type>
</mime-info>
```

Firefox now renders markdown for all users on the machine, rather than offering to download the files.

I'm sure this will work for other flavors and versions of Linux, but I've only tried it on the one I'm using, Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Answer (score 1):

I tried [Kazark's solution](/a/696362) with no success. So I restored the `mimeTypes.rdf` file to the default content and it worked.

To do so:

- In a terminal: `firefox --ProfileManager`
- Create a dummy profile and start Firefox with it
- Then in `~/.mozilla/firefox/`, copy `mimeTypes.rdf` from `*.dummy` directory to your profile directory (probably `*.default`)
- Restart Firefox and test

Answer (score 0):

I installed https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/markdown-viewer-webext/ right now. It is a signed Add-on from the official Mozilla Add-ons Repository and it is compatible with multiprocess. Cool. :)

Answer (score 0):

to simplify run this in terminal

```
echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>
<mime-info xmlns='http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/shared-mime-info'>
  <mime-type type=\"text/markdown\">
    <glob pattern=\"*.md\"/>
    <glob pattern=\"*.mkd\"/>
    <glob pattern=\"*.mkdn\"/>
    <glob pattern=\"*.mdwn\"/>
    <glob pattern=\"*.mdown\"/>
    <glob pattern=\"*.markdown\"/>
  </mime-type>
</mime-info>" > ~/.local/share/mime/packages/text-markdown.xml;
update-mime-database ~/.local/share/mime
```

and in the extension on advance options, allows the file access

take note, I change

> <mime-type type="text/plain">

to

> <mime-type type="text/markdown">

so you can associate markdown files to open with firefox separately to other text files